# Hide Mouse Cursor on Unity Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

how to hide mouse cursor on unity in android phone.
I am trying to hide mouse mouse cursor in android phone on unity or their is any other way to hide mouse cursor on android phone?

Comment: What have you tried ? What are your research efforts ?

Comment: i am tried unity code and it is working correctly on laptop (both hiding icon and moving character) but when i connect my mouse to phone and run the application it is not hiding mouse icon but it is moving my character in unity.
i find on other links but their is not any authentic answer available for this

Comment: FYI I've added support for this. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not supply API for hiding the cursor, therefor Unity can not hide or change the cursor default image on an Android device.
I know this question is old and the situation is actually much older, but the issue still holds.

I can not find an official source to confirm that, this conclusion is based on many similar questions, all of which are never answered, or answered with someone saying it's not possible (or answers which do not relate to android)

e.g. same complaint from 2015: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-hide-bluetooth-mouse-cursor-on-android.357463/

I do hope the API will allow that in future versions.

Comment: This is wrong. Android 8.0+ supports this for years now. iOS & iPadOS since 14.0 also support this. Its called pointer-capture.

Answer (score 0):

This is called pointer-capture which will hide mouse on Android, iOS & iPadOS.
I've added support for this here. Gets you PC like input for mobile platforms.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/mobile-input-capture-221017

Answer (score -2):

You can hide cursor by using **Cursor.visible = false;**

If any confusion get help from these links:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-visible.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-showCursor.html

Comment: this command only hides cursor on windows but not in my android phone.